# Why aren't snow golems working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Tekkit 3.1.2/1.2.5

We just set up a new tekkit server a week or so ago, and today I went to make a snow golem, but the golem wouldn't spawn after I placed the pumpkin. I made sure I was in an area where mobs could spawn, so that can't be the problem ... is there a flag or something that the server admin needs to set to allow snow golem/iron golems to spawn?

Comment: Tekkit isn't running the latest version of Minecraft. It may be that snow golems aren't in the game yet. I'll check.

Comment: According to the minecraft wiki, snow golems were introduced in beta1.9 pre ... 1.2.5 should include them, I thought.

Comment: This is just up for posterity's sake anyway ... we're moving on to tekkit lite.

Comment: Yes but it's more about the principle. Bugs aren't acceptable just because you don't care about them.

Comment: Hence posterity's sake. If I didn't think it was worthwhile, I'd have deleted the post.